# MySQL Splitting string value separated by comma using INSERT INTO/SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have a field named names in a table. This field shows "last_name, first_name". I am trying to take that field from the names table and insert the values into a new table into 2 different columns labeled last_name and first_name.  I have tried the following codes:

```
INSERT INTO usernames (last_name,first_name)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,',',1),',',-1) as last_name,
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,',',2),',',-1) as first_name
FROM person;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO usernames (last_name,first_name)
SELECT IF(LOCATE(', ',name)>0
SUBSTRING(name,1,LOCATE(', ',name)-1) AS last_name,
IF(LOCATE(', ',name)>0
SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(', ',name)+1),NULL) AS first_name
FROM person;
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with this code. Any help Is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Larry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query is almost ok, but second SELECT is not needed. check the syntax of SELECT in documentation.

```
INSERT INTO usernames (last_name,first_name)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,',',1),',',-1) as last_name,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,',',2),',',-1) as first_name
FROM person;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Inna Tichman.  That worked beautifully